# spherical coordinates javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hy!
I'm new in javascript, and I try to calculate the distance between two (GNNS) points which are given in spherical coordinates? My script:

```
    function spherical_dist() {

        fi_A = document.sphere.fi_A.value;
        lambda_A = document.sphere.lambda_A.value;
        fi_B = document.sphere.fi_B.value;
        lambda_B = document.sphere.lambda_B.value;

        R = 6378000;

        dlambda_AB = lambda_B - lambda_A;
        nu_AB = Math.acos( sin(fi_A) * Math.sin(fi_B) + Math.cos(fi_A) * Math.cos(fi_B) * Math.cos(dlambda_AB) );
        ro = 180/Math.PI;
        S_AB = R * nu_AB / ro;

        document.sphere.S_AB.value=S_AB;
    }
```

My question is: Is it syntactically correct? 
I want to write a HTMH code for one of my homeworks (new in HTML too). The whole script:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Distance between two coordinates in spherical coordinate system</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2">
</head>

<script language="JavaScript">
    function init() {
        document.sphere.S_AB.value="";
        document.sphere.fi_A.value="";
        document.sphere.lambda_A.value="";
        document.sphere.fi_B.value="";
        document.sphere.lambda_B.value="";
    }

    function sz_enter() {
        if (event.keyCode==13) {
            spherical_dist();
        }
    }

    function spherical_dist() {

        fi_A = document.sphere.fi_A.value;
        lambda_A = document.sphere.lambda_A.value;
        fi_B = document.sphere.fi_B.value;
        lambda_B = document.sphere.lambda_B.value;

        R = 6378000;

        dlambda_AB = lambda_B - lambda_A;
        nu_AB = Math.acos( sin(fi_A) * Math.sin(fi_B) + Math.cos(fi_A) * Math.cos(fi_B) * Math.cos(dlambda_AB) );
        ro = 180/Math.PI;
        S_AB = R * nu_AB / ro;

        document.sphere.S_AB.value=S_AB;
    }
</script>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000">
    <form name="sphere" method="post" action="">

        <p>P1 Longitude: <input type="text" name="fi_A"></p>

        <p>P1 Latitude: <input type="text" name="lambda_A"></p>

        <p>P2 Longitude: <input type="text" name="fi_B"></p>

        <p>P2 Latitude: <input type="text" name="lambda_B" onFocus="init();"></p>

        <p><input type="button" name="start" value="Calculate" onClick="spherical_dist();"></p>

        <hr>

        <p>
        Distance between the two points [m]: <input type="text" name="S_AB" size="10" readonly>
        </p>
    </form>

    Explanation: <br>
    - Here comes some explanation
</body>
```

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: To find out if it's syntactically correct you can run it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you are asking, but if you have two points in spherical coordinates,(ρ₁,θ₁,ϕ₁) and (ρ₂,θ₂,ϕ₂), the distance between them is √((ρ₁×sin(ϕ₁)×cos(θ₁)-(ρ₂×sin(ϕ₂)×cos(θ₂)))^2+((ρ₁×sin(ϕ₁)×cos(θ₁)-(ρ₂×sin(ϕ₂)×sin(θ₂)))^2+((ρ₁×cos(ϕ₁)-(ρ₂×cos(ϕ₂)))^2.
I got this answer by:

1. Spherical Coordinates (ρ,θ,ϕ) -> Cartesian Coordiantes (ρ×sin(ϕ)×cos(θ),⍴×sin(ϕ)×cos(θ),⍴×cos(ϕ))
2. Subtract the coordinates from one another to be able to just calculate the distance from the origin.
3. Use the Pythagorean Theorem on your new Cartesian coordinates. √x^2+y^2+z^2 = distance

I hope this helps you; I'm following this question so I'll try to get back to you as quick as I can if you have any questions!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).